# Difference between JACKSON and JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I want to know difference Difference between JACKSON and JSON? i am using JSON data format in android. Tell me the advantages and disadvantages of JACKSON AND JSON?

Comment: Jackson is a library used to handle JSON. Google can tell you this also.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks research and helps nobody.

Comment: Kayaman question is a problem that face some person.

Comment: I just Googled this question and my research took me to this page....

Answer (score 8):

> I want to know difference Difference between JACKSON and JSON?

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a data format.

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is a Java library that can parse JSON.

Comment: @ComonsWare can u tell me simple parsing json example of Jackson lib?